# What is the meaning of MCOConnectionLogType to -1?

Tags: mailcore2

What is the meaning of MCOConnectionLogType to -1?
In the process of sending,the following code:

```
 smtpSess.connectionLogger = ^(void * connectionID, MCOConnectionLogType type, NSData * data){
//            NSLog(@"connectionID==>%@",connectionID);
            NSLog(@"type==>%i",type);
            NSLog(@"data==>%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        };
```

Comment: Does it happen when sending a standard email with success?

Comment: In the process of subsection send attachments

Comment: You can just ignore that kind logs. I'll make them disappear.